# What language for live webcam streaming?

Tags: streaming, webcam

I would like to save audio and video from a webcam, directly from the browser.
Then I want to broadcast it to other users.
What language/tech should I use (in browser and server side)?

It seems that Flash can record a webcam in the browser, is there any other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## No

From the browser Flash/Flex/AS is the way to go.